# Why does the program display warning passing argument 1 of 'circularswap' makes pointer from integer without a cast?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I am working on this problem:

```
Given an array p[5], write a function to shift it circularly left by two positions. Thus, if p[0] = 15, p[1]= 30, p[2] = 28, p[3]= 19 and p[4] = 61 then after the shift p[0] = 28, p[1] = 19, p[2] = 61, p[3] = 15 and p[4] = 30. Call this function for a (4 x 5 ) matrix and get its rows left shifted.
```

Here's the code I tried:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    
#include <stdio.h>
void circularswap(int arr[][5],int n,int m){ int arr1[n][m],i,j;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        for (j=0;j<m;j++){
            arr1[i][j]=*(*(arr+i)+j);
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<m;i++){
        *(*(arr+i)+0)=arr1[i][2];
        *(*(arr+i)+1)=arr1[i][3];
        *(*(arr+i)+2)=arr1[i][4];
        *(*(arr+i)+3)=arr1[i][0];
        *(*(arr+i)+4)=arr1[i][1];
    }
        for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        for (j=0;j<5;j++){
            printf ("%d",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}
int main(){ int i,j;
    int arr[4][5]={(15,30,28,19,61),(15,30,28,19,61),(15,30,28,19,61),(15,30,28,19,61)};
    circularswap((arr,4,5));
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, this shows up warnings. Can someone please tell why the warnings pop up and how to remove them?

Comment: *"Unfortunately, this shows up warnings"* - what do you think those warnings mean? And this code should emit a lot more warnings than the one you mentioned.

Comment: Please see the edited code everyone

Comment: My aplogies @WhozCraig, can you please correct the code as I am new to programming?

Comment: [Please see the warning/error stack here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8da3a1586b00d7cf).

Comment: `*(*(arr+i)+j)` please unlearn this. Just always write `arr[i][j]`, thank you!

Comment: New edited code: https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/412234 gives segmentation fault, please help. @WhozCraig

Comment: Please do not remove your code from the question. That is considered vandalism. Also don't provid code in external links. Everything required to solve your question shall be included in the question itself. Rolled back the last edit.

Comment: @Gerhardh The new code in comment is not formatted properly, that is why given in external link. I am really sorry, I am a new user, I hope you understand.

Comment: No problem. You can also edit the question to apply proper formatting and also add more code if you want to share updated version.

Answer (score 4):

You have to many parentheses when calling the function.

The expression `(arr,4,5)` is using [the comma *operator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) and will evaluate all the sub-expressions in the list, but return only the `5`.

I.e. your call is really the same as `circularswap(5)`, which is incorrect in multiple ways.

To solve your problem drop the inner parentheses:

```
circularswap(arr,4,5);
```

---

You have a similar problem when initializing your array: You use parentheses `()` instead of curly braces `{}`.

So the array definition is really equal to:

```
int arr[4][5]={ { 61 }, { 61 }, { 61 }, { 61 } };
```

<sub>[Note how I use curly-braces in the example above]</sub>

---

On another note, for any pointer `p` and index `i`, the expression `*(p + i)` is *exactly* equal to `p[i]`. The latter is easier to read and understand, and also less to write.

It matters especially when using arrays of arrays like you do, where e.g. `*(*(arr+i)+0)` could be replaced with `arr[i][0]`.

Comment: This now gives segmentation fault

Comment: Any other changes which are required?

Answer (score 0):

You declared a two-dimensional array

```
 int arr[4][5]
```

So elements of the array in turn are one-dimensional arrays. You may initialize a one-dimensional array by an initializer list or a string literal if the array element type is char.

However you are using an expression of a scalar type with the comma operator like

```
(15,30,28,19,61)
```

The value of the expression is the value of the last operand that is `61`. In fact your initialization looks like

```
int arr[4][5]=
{
    [0] = 61,
    [1] = 61,
    [2] = 61,
    [3] = 61
};
```

that under the hood looks like for example

```
a[0] = 61;
```

That is you are trying to assign the value 61 to an array of the type `int[5]`.

You need to enclose the lists in braces like

```
int arr[4][5] =
{
    { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
    { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
    { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
    { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 }
};
```

Also in the assignment there is written that you need to write a function that shifts element of a one-dimensional array to the left. But in your program there is no such a function.

Moreover your function `circularswap` has bugs. For example in this loop

```
for (i=0;i<m;i++){
    *(*(arr+i)+0)=arr1[i][2];
    *(*(arr+i)+1)=arr1[i][3];
    *(*(arr+i)+2)=arr1[i][4];
    *(*(arr+i)+3)=arr1[i][0];
    *(*(arr+i)+4)=arr1[i][1];
}
```

there is used the variable `m` instead of `n` and a magic numbers like `4`. So using the variable `m` instead of the variable `n` and using the magic number `4` instead of using the variable `m` in an inner loop makes your loop senseless.

Also though in the assignment there is written to circularly shift elements of rows by 2 positions you should always write a more general function that allows the user to specify the number of shifts.

Thus you need to write a function that circularly shifts elements to the left and call the function for each row specifying the number of shifts equal to 2.

The program can look the following way as it is shown below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void circular_shift_left( int a[], size_t n, size_t pos )
{
    if ( n != 0 )
    {
        pos = pos % n;
    
        if ( pos != 0 )
        {
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < pos; i++ )
            {
                int tmp = a[0];
                memmove( a, a + 1, ( n - 1 ) * sizeof( *a ) );
                a[n-1] = tmp;
            }
        }           
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 4, N = 5 };
    int a[M][N] =
    {
        { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
        { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
        { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 },
        { 15, 30, 28, 19, 61 }
    };
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        circular_shift_left( a[i], N, 2 );
    }
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < M; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    putchar( '\n' );
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
15 30 28 19 61 
15 30 28 19 61 
15 30 28 19 61 
15 30 28 19 61 

28 19 61 15 30 
28 19 61 15 30 
28 19 61 15 30 
28 19 61 15 30
```

Comment: Can you please tell why my loop doesn't make sense?

Comment: This is the code I am talking about,  not the one posted in original question

Comment: @GirGr For starters the number of rows is specified by the variable n not by the variable m. Secondly you are using the magic number 4 instead of using a loop with the variable m.